# FaceRecognition.java in JavaCV Train Text File pattern

Tags: java, android, opencv, javacv, face-recognition

I'm currently running the sample code FaceRecognition.java by reed the code found [here](https://github.com/danieljonker/PersonFinder/blob/master/Person%20finder/src/danie/jonker/personfinder/FaceRecognition.java).

The sample for the train text file for images is in this format:

```
1 myName /sdcard/FaceDB/s1/myName1.jpg
1 myName /sdcard/FaceDB/s1/myName2.jpg
1 myName /sdcard/FaceDB/s1/myName3.jpg
1 myName /sdcard/FaceDB/s1/myName4.jpg
2 otherName /sdcard/FaceDB/s2/otherName1.jpg
2 otherName /sdcard/FaceDB/s2/otherName2.jpg
2 otherName /sdcard/FaceDB/s2/otherName3.jpg
2 otherName /sdcard/FaceDB/s2/otherName4.jpg
```

I am wondering how this is done, and what is the explanation behind this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would like to point you to this article http://www.shervinemami.info/faceRecognition.html which does explain everything you want to know. The code is in C/C++, but I hope it is not too difficult to follow.

The file just follows this format:

```
<person no.> <person name> <location of the the person's face image>
```

You can actually create your own format. It is about your design on how your program can find and read those input images.

Comment: thank you, but i want to know what is the result of the face recognition, based on the code FaceRecognition.java how should i know the result if the recognition is succesful?

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstand your question here. From the FaceRecognition.java code, it will write the results to the log file like https://github.com/danieljonker/PersonFinder/blob/master/logcat.txt. Search for 'nearest ='; the number after this string is the person no. in the training data that best matches with the test image.

Comment: thanks , but the nearest always returns one of the train image number , even if the the picture i try to recognize is not among them. how should i know if the person is not on the training images?

Comment: @PogsDBest, have you ever found the solution for the nearest?? I'm having the same problem..